# How to store and index JSON data in PostgreSQL for better search perfomance?

Tags: postgresql

I have read several articles about PostgreSQL data types, indexes, and full-text search. However, I still have doubts about the most efficient way to implement the following requirements.
I was thinking of posting a separate question to ask about the best way to index particular data, but I decided to post a single question to provide more context.

**1. I need to store log messages from another application that are in the next format:**

```
{
    "ID": 5856,
    "TimeStamp": "2023-10-28T13:32:43Z",
    "Level": "Info",
    "Message": "Some system generated message about the current record",
    "User": "John Lennon",
    "Cube": "Sales Actuals",
    "Tuple": [
        "2023-Nov",
        "Canada",
        ...,
        "Product 123",
        "Units sold"
    ],
    "OldValue": "237",
    "NewValue": "280"
}
```

The **Tuple** is an array of coordinates (or simply elements) of a given multidimensional **Cube**. A cube can have 2 or more dimensions, so a tuple can have 2 or more elements.

**2. We anticipate having a sizable volume of data, ranging from 10 to 100 million records, or even more**

**3. The records should be optimized for searching by the next criteria, one or multiple criteria can be applied at the same time:**

- TimeStamp: BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2, i.e. BETWEEN 2023-10-27T00:00:00Z AND 2023-11-05T23:59:59Z
- Level: the exact value, i.e. "Info"
- User: the exact value, i.e. "John Lennon"
- Cube: the exact value, i.e. "Sales Actuals"
- Tuple: multiple pattern search, case insensitive, i.e.: contains("2023") & contains("canad") & contains("Units sold")
- Message: full-text search
- OldValue: full-text search
- NewValue: full-text search

We could probably have 1 full-text search by a combined field: Tuple.join(" ") + Message + OldValue + NewValue

**4. The search results should be fed to my front-end in JSON format:**

We can have additional columns created to build indices or optimize the search performance, but in the end, the query should return the original JSON records as they were retrieved from the resource application (key order and white spaces do not matter).

I'm using Python to extract log records from the source application and insert it into Postgresql, so I can massage data if needed.

I need help designing the table and indices, in particular I'm trying to figure out:

Should I store the records in a single JSONB format?
Should I index every field that I need to use in my query filters?
Would storing some fields as separate columns and indexing them make any performance difference?

I'd appreciate any input on optimizing the performance.

Comment: I see no reason to use jsonb here.  Make a traditional table, with a join table for the tuple. You get referencial integrity and normal SQL indexing and queries. Query results can be output as json as needed.

Comment: Your example "Tuple" doesn't how anything I would regard as  'coordinates'.  Are you using the word in a specialized or peculiar way?

Comment: Your example OldValue and NewValue each consist of a single token, which looks like an integer.  FTS doesn't make much sense in that context.  Maybe your example is unrepresentative of your real data and we could benefit from a more representative example.

Comment: I initially considered using a traditional table with a separate column for each field. I'm curious if anybody could speak of the performance of converting JSON to columns when saving the logs and converting the data back to JSON when reading the logs VS storing and indexing JSON data

Comment: Tuple coordinates represent dimension elements from a multidimensional (OLAP) cube. A cube can have 2 or more dimensions. A Tuple will contain an element from each dimension. OldValue and NewValuem could be a numeric or string value. Users may search for a specific value

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retrieve the JSON data exactly as written in the source, then you need to use json, not jsonb.  The jsonb will normalize things like whitespace and ordering of the keys of objects and so cannot regurgitate the original data exactly.  I guess it depends on how stringent the requirement is.  Maybe you just mean the output needs to be JSON, not that it needs to be bytewise identical to the input.

You could copy the different single-valued fields from the json into their own columns in the table.  This would make for nicer looking queries, but would also lead to higher storage as the data is unnecessarily duplicated.  I would generally prefer using functional/operational index instead of duplicating the data.

So you would make the index

```
 create index  on j ((data->>'Level'));
```

Then query `where data->>'Level' = 'Info'`

Rather than using a separate column and querying with the cleaner `where level='Info'`.

You will probably need to define some helper functions to deal with "TimeStamp", as the cast of text to timestamptz is not immutable and so can't be used directly in an index definition.

For "Tuple", you could build a functional gin index like maybe

```
create index on j using gin ( jsonb_to_tsvector('english', (data->'Tuple')::jsonb,'"String"'));
```

You might want some multicolumn indexes if the things tested for equality are commonly used together and neither one is highly selective on its own.  But the considerations here are no different when using operational indexes than they would be using true column indexes, it is just extra keystrokes:

```
create index on j ((data->>'Level'),(data->>'User'));
```

Comment: Many thanks, @jjanes. I am new to PostgreSQL and I truly appreciate all the help and examples you have provided. Yes I meant the output needs to be in JSON format, key order and whitespace do not matter.  Some fields (like timestamp and user) may be used more often, but in general, I should expect any combination of filters. You confirmed my gut feeling to store data in JSON format and focus on proper indexing. I'm going to play with JSONB and index examples you provided.